# linux column command or other -- want some padding before output

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using the linux column command in a bash v4 script to put out data in columnar format which I need.

I don't want to specify a width of the first column of the data, because I don't know how long it will be, so I want the column command to just figure it out appropriately.

However to fit in with my other output from the script, I would like there to be some leading spaces before each line in the output.  How do I add leading space?  Right now I've simply got:

```
  echo -ne $output | column -t
```

Comment: One option might be to pipe the output of `column -t` to `sed 's/^/    /'` to add four spaces (that's how many I typed; I see that MarkDown is only really willing to show one — but it handles non-breaking spaces OK).

Comment: Great.  Of course, you are right, I forgot about sed for some reason.   If you want to put that in as the answer I can give credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to pipe the output of `column -t` to

```
sed 's/^/    /'
```

to add four spaces — you get to choose how many you want, of course.